# Application Cache Error: Invalid or missing manifest origin trial token

Tags: javascript, extjs, html5-appcache

I have a web app that has been running without issue for the last three years.  It was contructed with the ExtJS framework. All of the sudden, none of my customers could reach the site.  Upon investigation I am getting this error on the console and I have never seen it nor do I know what it means.  Can anyone explain this and let me know how to fix it?  Thank you.

```
Application Cache Error event: Invalid or missing manifest origin trial token
```

Using Chrome, Brave and Firefox.

Comment: Have removed the `apache` tag and added [`html5-appcache`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-appcache) instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is only a wild guess, but might be related to app-cache removal in Chrome version 84/85. Downgrading to Chrome version 83 could either proof or disproof this suspicion. [FireFox](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/84) also removed it in version 84; and Safari also ditched it.

This explains it in more detail: https://web.dev/appcache-removal/

> Starting with Chrome 90, AppCache will be fully removed for everyone, even those who had signed up for the origin trial.

So there still is the option for [a trial](https://developers.chrome.com/origintrials/#/register_trial/1776670052997660673) (the quick resolution) - but on the long run, this won't help. This would at least enable your customers to use the application in the meanwhile (at least on Chrome) and should provide plenty of time for a proper fix (which means: migrate to  Service Worker API).